# How to set z-index of javascript default alert popup?

Tags: javascript

Javascript code

```
 <script>
 function myFunction()
 {
 alert("Welcome!");
 }
 </script>
```

As the question says, i want to set the z-index of default alert popup. Is this possible ?

Comment: No. you have no control over modal dialogs.

Comment: The alert popup is not a DOM element, CSS doesn't apply to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an **alert popup** is not a DOM Element, CSS cannot be applied, as if you alert `style` of a popup, it will return **undefined.**  Think about it: you can't access javascript variables through CSS, because when it comes to modal dialogs,

[image: You have no control :P]

### But don't worry, because remember:

[image: Sometimes you don't have control :)]

What you *can* do, however, is manually create a DOM modal dialog.  [Here is an example of how to make one.](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/modal-dialog.html)